# Bizarre SwiftUI behavior: ViewModel class + @Binding is breaking when using @Environment(\.presentationMode)

Tags: swiftui

I keep finding very strange SwiftUI bugs that only pop up under very specific circumstances . For example, I have a form that is shown as a model sheet. This form has a ViewModel, and shows a `UITextView` (via `UIViewRepresentable` and a `@Binding` - it's all in the code below).

Everything works absolutely fine, you can run the code below and you'll see all the two-way bindings working as expected: type in one field and it changes in the other, and vice-versa. However, as soon as you un-comment the line `@Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode`, then the two-way binding in the TextView breaks. You will also notice that the ViewModel prints "HERE" twice.

What the hell is going on? My guess is that as soon as `ContentView` shows the modal, the value of `presentationMode` changes, which then re-renders the sheet (so, `FormView`). That would explain the duplicate "HERE" getting logged. But, why does that break the two-way text binding?

One workaround is to not use a ViewModel, and simply have an `@State` property directly in the `FormView`. But that is not a great solution as I have a bunch of logic in my real-world form, which I don't want to move to the form view. So, does anyone have a better solution?

```swift
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct TextView: UIViewRepresentable {
  @Binding var text: String

  func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    Coordinator(self)
  }

  func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
    let uiTextView = UITextView()
    uiTextView.delegate = context.coordinator
    return uiTextView
  }

  func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: Context) {
    uiView.text = self.text
  }

  class Coordinator : NSObject, UITextViewDelegate {
    var parent: TextView

    init(_ view: TextView) {
      self.parent = view
    }

    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
      self.parent.text = textView.text
    }

    func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
      self.parent.text = textView.text
    }
  }
}

struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var showForm = false
  //@Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      Text("Hello")
      .navigationBarItems(trailing: trailingNavigationBarItem)
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $showForm) {
      FormView()
    }
  }

  private var trailingNavigationBarItem: some View {
    Button("Form") {
      self.showForm = true
    }
  }
}

struct FormView: View {
  @ObservedObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      Form {
        Section(header: Text(viewModel.text)) {
          TextView(text: $viewModel.text)
            .frame(height: 200)
        }

        Section(header: Text(viewModel.text)) {
          TextField("Text", text: $viewModel.text)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var text = ""

  init() {
    print("HERE")
  }
}
```

Comment: Why would you need `presentationMode` in `ContentView`? Isn't it root view? If I place `presentationMode` in `FormView`, as would intended to close it, then everything works as expected.

Comment: No, it’s not the root view in my real app. Just believe me that it’s needed there :) ContentView is pushed onto a NavigationView and needs to be able to pop itself programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a workaround: store the ViewModel on the ContentView, not on the FormView, and pass it in to the FormView.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var showForm = false
  @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode

  private let viewModel = ViewModel()

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      Text("Hello")
      .navigationBarItems(trailing: trailingNavigationBarItem)
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $showForm) {
      FormView(viewModel: self.viewModel)
    }
  }

  private var trailingNavigationBarItem: some View {
    Button("Form") {
      self.showForm = true
    }
  }
}

struct FormView: View {
  @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      Form {
        Section(header: Text(viewModel.text)) {
          TextView(text: $viewModel.text)
            .frame(height: 200)
        }

        Section(header: Text(viewModel.text)) {
          TextField("Text", text: $viewModel.text)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var text = ""

  init() {
    print("HERE")
  }
}
```

The only thing is that the ViewModel is now instantiated right when the ContentView is opened, even if you never open the FormView. Feels a bit wasteful. Especially when you have a big List, with NavigationLinks to a bunch of detail pages, which now all create their presented-as-a-sheet FormView's ViewModel up front, even if you never leave the List page.

Sadly I can't turn the ViewModel into a struct, as I actually need to (asynchronously) mutate state and then eventually I run into the `Escaping closure captures mutating 'self' parameter` compiler error. Sigh. So yeah, I am stuck with using a class.

The root of the issue is still that FormView is instantiated twice (because of `@Environment(\.presentationMode)`), which causes two ViewModels to be created as well (which my workaround solves by passing in one copy to both FormViews basically). But it's still weird that this broke `@Binding`, since the standard TextFields did work as expected.

There are still a lot of weird gotcha's like this with SwiftUI, I really hope this becomes simpler to manage soon. If anyone can explain the behavior of sheets, `ObservableObject` classes (viewmodels), `@Environment(\.presentationMode)` and `@Binding` put together, I'm all ears.

Comment: Same problem happened to me and I managed to solve by using your solution. Thank you.

Comment: Commenting to say this is still an issue in Feb 2022 using latest and greatest ver.